# imbalance data between train set and test set

Tags: machine-learning

I have a train set with more class 1 but less class 0, while I have a test set with more class 0 but less class 1. I have applied threshold adjustment into cross-validation. But it doesn't help to increase the performance in the test set.
Is there any suggestion to increase my performance, I got super low recall score.